# Instagram api endpoint for saved collections

Tags: instagram, instagram-api, instagramapi-mgp25

Does Instagram api have an endpoint that returns user's saved collections? If not, is there a different way i can get the data?

Instagram Platform api is deprecating. How good it is to use instagram graph api for non-business use?

Comment: Check `mgp25` and use this class: https://github.com/mgp25/Instagram-API/blob/master/src/Request/Collection.php

Answer (score 5):

If using javascript you can use: https://github.com/dilame/instagram-private-api

some example code (you'd need to be authenticated):

```
const IG_API = require('instagram-private-api');
const ig = new IG_API.IgApiClient();

// get saved posts
const savedFeed = ig.feed.saved();
const mySavedPosts = await Promise.all([await savedFeed.items(), await savedFeed.items()]);
```